# Find max of date from different nodes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is my XML Code where I have multiple date nodes. I need to find the maximum date of all these dates which are not in any specific node order.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:Workers>
<ns1:Worker>
    <ns1:Summary>
        <ns1:Employee_ID>12345678</ns1:Employee_ID>
        <ns1:Name>David J Rock</ns1:Name>
    </ns1:Summary>
    <ns1:Personal>
        <ns1:Birth_Date>1965-05-03</ns1:Birth_Date>
    </ns1:Personal>
    <ns1:Status>
        <ns1:Employee_Status>Active</ns1:Employee_Status>
        <ns1:Active_Status_Date>2015-01-16</ns1:Active_Status_Date>
        <ns1:Hire_Date>2015-01-16</ns1:Hire_Date>
        <ns1:Original_Hire_Date>2012-04-16</ns1:Original_Hire_Date>
    </ns1:Status>
    <ns1:Position>
        <ns1:Effective_Date>2015-01-16</ns1:Effective_Date>
    </ns1:Position>
    <ns1:Compensation>
        <ns1:Effective_Date>2018-03-02</ns1:Effective_Date>
    </ns1:Compensation>
    <ns1:Additional_Information>
        <ns1:Location_Effective_Date>2015-01-16</ns1:Location_Effective_Date>
    </ns1:Additional_Information>
</ns1:Worker>
```

Comment: you could at least mention programming language you are using

Comment: Apologies, I am using XSLT to transform XML to XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sample doesn't even define the namespace for the `ns1` prefix it uses so you can't parse it with an XML parser but assuming you have any namespace declaration then a generic `max` use in XSLT 2 or 3 is `<xsl:value-of select="max(//*[not(*) and . castable as xs:date]/xs:date(.))"/>`: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwm